# Newsletter slow sending - delay between 2 mails to the same server / max e-mails per hour?

Tags: newsletter, flooding

I have to make a newsletter sending utility application which will collect the list of subscriber from our central database and send out the newsletter. I've considered the possibility to be blacklisted due to flooding if I just flush out all emails at once, so I decided to go on a desktop-based softwer which will email those slowly.

my question is

- what is the max emails per hour that may be addressed to the same email domain (recipient/incoming server)?
- or what should be delay between 2 e-mails to the same server for it doesn't consider it flooding?

whichever of the above applies more appropriate to the real-world of mail servers configuration...

thanks

Comment: i'd like to ask moderators to move this question to the ServerFault community where some SysAdmin may have more insight than programmers here.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implementing sending to max 600 e-mails per recipient domain. That seems to be working fine for some time now and sounds like an OK solution.

Still, some SysAdmin insight on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I make Thread.Sleep(2000) after every 2 mail

Comment: thanks for the comment, i've developed the algorithm to sort my recipients into collections per e-mail address domain, then send out one mail per each domain, then pause.

i've set to send max 500 or 600 mails per hour per recipient domain (app calculates pauses between rounds), i hope it'll be ok.

Comment: i hope it will be ok. But when i ve talked with my hosting company. They said the mail server they are using, i dont know how is yours, doesn't let non-stop mail sendindg, talked about daily limits and spam conditions. He adviced to me, pausing 1 second after each mail. the safetiest way he said

Comment: my ISP have no problem with the outgoing volume, they offered to whitelist unlimited sending volumes with authentication for sending if needed. but i still don't have the some common incoming limtations info per different ISPs (mine told me that 500-600 incoming is ok for them). no sysadmins here :)

Answer (score 0):

It's really going to vary by configuration, so there's not necessarily a one-size-fits-all answer.  You might want to check with your ISP - it's probably them or their upstream that you'd need to worry about.

Since you're sending a newsletter, could you add multiple recipients via BCC rather than individual messages?  That should be less "abusive" to all concerned.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment... but, it's not about my ISP, i've contacted with them and there is nothing i should worry about when sending out those emails. the incoming part worries me, and that's beyond my ISP.

the other thing, the BCC-ing just leads to being marked as spam. not the way to go.